# Is there a way to get google calendar events by passing email and password dynamically?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

In my application ,users have their own accounts ,when a user logs in and provides gmail credentials, i have to get the events in his calendar by making call to calendar API using service account .

Answer (score 1):

There is an api for accessing Google Calendar as you have noted it is called Google Calendar API.

In order to access private user data you must have the owner of that data's permission.  To get that permission you use Oauth2.

Accessing APIs using login and password is called client login and this was discontinued by Google around may 2015

Answer: No you can not access a users private Google Calendar data using their login and password.

Comment: i think i can i use this - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation , So that i can create a service account which will access to every user account in the domain . But it is limited to the users in the same domain .

Comment: If you are talking about users within your Gsuite account yes the admin of the Gsuite account can add the service account so that you will have access to all the users on the domain.   This will only work for usrs on the domain.   If they are normal users they would have to add your service account manually to their accounts.   If your question is related to gsuite then i think you should edit it and include that in your question.

Comment: Yeah my bad, i don't know what is a Gsuite until few hours ago , and what helped me is that the user's will be of same domain so i think i have to see how to implement this . Can you give me an example in python ?